# What do you call the cat sound that comes out from the throat like "pigeons"?

Tags: cats, vocalizations

I looked all over the net, but I couldn't find the answer.

My cats sometime do this weird nose without using their lips. it's cute and funny.

The sound comes out from the throat as if they are humming. It's like the "pigeons" voice but sharper ([Pigeons sound](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XF9Me96KMU4))

Is there a name for that?

Comment: it is hard to understand what you are asking but here is a link to some cat sounds https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMTQqQmJkGA  i guess it is the chirping(chatter)sound you are asking about,please clarify and edit it into your question.

Comment: I think it's purring @trondhansen

Comment: no no no it's more than purring. IT's like the pigeon sound. I can hear it. As if they are singing

Comment: check 0:59 of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_zKkBKu1fs

Answer (score 1):

It's called "purring" I guess. Not only domestic cats but many other cat species do it as well.

It is most commonly done when the cat is feeling special by you, like you are giving her care like a baby, the cat is very happy with you at the moment, and she expresses that she is very happy with you by "purring".

Not all cat do it, also some do it less, some do it more. It also differs from one cat breed to another.

Below is an excellent youtube video about "purring":

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_zKkBKu1fs

Also scientists say that cat "purring" is an excellent anti-depressant and a medicine for general mental health.

https://medium.com/the-establishment/cats-are-the-unsung-heroes-of-mental-health-2a78398f9f3

Comment: at 0:59 that's it!!!! it's purring but more than purring lolololol. so it's purring but with a higher tone. Still purring tho. I thought that it has another name

Answer (score 0):

I know the sound you mean. My Tortie cat makes the sound too when she's happy that I'm home. I call it "chirping". But I don't know if it has a more official name. I think the pigeon sound is called "cooing". So you could call it "cooing" when your kitty does it.